# Custom Routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I've looked around for a while now, but I'm not sure how best to describe my request to google, so thought I'd ask here ;)

In rails, I know that when you nest restful routes, you generally get something like:

> http://localhost/categories/1/articles/2

If you want something more meaningful, you can use slugs or friendly_id to get something like

> http://localhost/categories/all-your-needs/articles/rock-out-with-this-article

(assuming you have unique names).

My question is, how can I remove the controller from the url rewriter so you get something like:

> http://localhost/all-your-needs/rock-out-with-this-article

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. You can use something like this:

**Rails 2:**

```
map.show_article ':category/:article', :controller => "articles", :action => "show"
```

**Edit:**

Ok. Here you have the urls for the other REST actions:

```
map.edit_article ':category/:article/edit', :controller => "articles", :action => "edit".
```

For update add `:conditions => { :method => :post }` to the previous one.

For delete, use the first one with `:conditions => { :method => :delete }`.

For new and create, you can use:

```
map.new_article ':category/new', :controller => "articles", :action => "new"
```

and for create the same but with `:conditions => { :method => :post }`. I hope I've been able to help you!

Comment: actually, what Rolpege supplied does work ... but only for one action (show). How can I expand that to encompass all actions (or nest more controllers)?

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry Rolpege, I was the one who misunderstood!

Comment: But BEWARE to put this line at the bottom of your routes.rb file => this declaration could be fetched by too many routes: foo/bar for instance

Comment: @apneadiving: Haha, no problem. @Maximus: Edited the answer to add the other REST actions.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this wrong, but using :method => :post doesn't work for updates (you have to use :method => :put instead)